# BoundaryNorm, unexpected behavior

Tags: python, matplotlib, colorbar, colormap, normalize

*My code:*

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import colors

x = y = np.linspace(0, 10, 51)
X, Y = np.meshgrid(x, y)
Z = X+Y # Z.min() => 0, Z.max() => 20 
cf = plt.contourf(X, Y, Z,
                  levels=[5, 10, 15],
                  norm=colors.BoundaryNorm([5, 10, 15], 256, extend='both'))
cb = plt.colorbar(cf, extend='both')
plt.show()
```

*Its output:*

[image]

*My expectations:*

- in the main plot, a dark blue lower triangle in place of the white one,
- ditto, a bright yellow upper triangle,
- the colorbar decorated with an upper bright yellow triangle and a lower dark blue triangle.

**My question:**

What have I done wrong?

Comment: For a contour plot, the colored regions are defined by the levels, the norm only can change colors. `plt.contourf(..., levels=[5, 10, 15])` only creates two sets of polygons: between 5 and 10, and another between 10 and 15.  The rest of the plot stays empty (by default the white background color is visible). Maybe is `plt.contourf(..., levels=[-1000, 5, 10, 15, 1000])` closer to what you want?

Comment: Note that `plt.contourf()` does "its own thing" with the colorbar.  If you try `cf = plt.scatter(X, Y, c=Z, norm=colors.BoundaryNorm([5, 10, 15], 256, extend='both'))`, you'll see a more standard colorbar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @JohanC notes, colorbar does strange things with a contour.  However, in this simple case, why are you using BoundaryNorm?

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import colors

x = y = np.linspace(0, 10, 51)
X, Y = np.meshgrid(x, y)
Z = X+Y # Z.min() => 0, Z.max() => 20
cf = plt.contourf(X, Y, Z,
                  levels=[5, 10, 15], extend='both')
cb = plt.colorbar(cf, extend='both')
plt.show()
```

Does exactly what you want.

[image]

Comment: Jody, it's not that I want to use `BoundaryNorm` in a simple case. but rather I want to use it in a more complex case and applying it to a simple case made, in my opinion, a good MWE…  That said, it seems that `contourf` , when we don't use explicitly a BN does exactly what we want... and probably will do the right thing also in my more complicated case. Thank you.

Comment: … in your opinion, `contourf` being _confused_ when a BN is explicitly used, is it a bug?

Comment: My understanding is that a boundary norm is basically redundant with contour levels, and gives a contour-level like norm for pcolormesh or other colormapped artists.   However, people use Matplotlib in different ways so my understanding could be wrong.